# Yii radioButtonList: radio button and item description are in separate lines

Tags: yii, radiobuttonlist

I've defined a radio button list in Yii as following:

```
<?php echo  $form->radioButtonList($model, 'send_option', $email_exist); ?>
```

Here $email_exist variable is set in the controller.

[image: The radio button looks like this.]

The problem is radio button is in one line and item description is in another line. I want both are in the same line.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think your HTML element's width is not enough for fitting both. Try by increasing the width of HTML element where you put this radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use template option , this example for checkBoxList:

```
<ul>
<?php echo CHtml::checkBoxList('checkBoxList','',$data, array(
    'id'=>'checklist',
    'name'=>'checklist',
    'template'=>'<li>{input} {label}</li>',
));?>
</ul>
```

Note: it's same with radioButtonList